# AIRFLOW DAG for uploading files fails when files not there

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have an airflow DAG that works perfectly when files are present, but error->fails when the source files are not there.

Randomly, I recieve files from a given source, that my DAG picks up and processes.  While I need to run the DAG daily, files are not necessarily there daily.  Could be monday, wednesday, or even sunday evening.

I'm not worried about days with no new files. i worry about days when new files come and it breaks.

How do I tell the DAG that when no file exist then gracefully exit with success?
My DAG below (please ignore schedule setting.  I'm still in development mode):

```
import airflow
from airflow import models
from airflow.operators.gcs_to_bq import GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator
from airflow.operators.gcs_to_gcs import GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator

args = {
    'owner': 'Airflow',
    'start_date': airflow.utils.dates.days_ago(2),
    'email': ['email@gmail.com'],
    'email_on_failure': True,
    'schedule_interval': 'None',
}

dag = models.DAG(
    dag_id='Source1_Ingestion',
    default_args=args
)

# [START load ATTOM File to STAGING]
load_File_to_Source1_RAW = GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator(
    task_id='Source1_GCS_to_GBQ_Raw',
    bucket='Source1_files',
    source_objects=['To_Process/*.txt'],
    destination_project_dataset_table='Source1.Source1_RAW',
    schema_fields=[
        {'name': 'datarow', 'type': 'STRING', 'mode': 'NULLABLE'},
    ],
    field_delimiter='§',
    write_disposition='WRITE_TRUNCATE',
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='GCP_EDW_Staging',
    bigquery_conn_id='GCP_EDW_Staging',
    dag=dag)
# [END howto_operator_gcs_to_bq]

# [START move files to Archive]
archive_attom_files = GoogleCloudStorageToGoogleCloudStorageOperator(
    task_id='Archive_Source1_Files',
    source_bucket='Source1_files',
    source_object='To_Process/*.txt',
    destination_bucket='Source1_files',
    destination_object='Archive/',
    move_object=True,
    google_cloud_storage_conn_id='GCP_EDW_Staging',
    dag=dag
)

# [END move files to archive]

load_File_to_Source1_RAW.set_downstream(archive_Source1_files)
```

Comment: Have you thought about using a sensor to detect files first? We use a pattern that has a sensor operator test for presence first, then pull if the data exists. Happy to write up a more detailed answer, but wanted to check if you've ruled that out first.

Comment: no I haven't.  I'm still a beginner.  if I do not detect a file, my question still stands.  How do I exit gracefully?  How do I do this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way to approach this would be to add a Sensor Operator to the workflow.

Nehil Jain [describes sensors nicely](https://medium.com/snaptravel/airflow-part-2-lessons-learned-793fa3c0841e):

> Sensors are a special kind of airflow operator that will keep running until a certain criterion is met. For example, you know a file will arrive at your S3 bucket during certain time period, but the exact time when the file arrives is inconsistent.

For your use case, it looks like there's a [Google Cloud Sensor](http://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/sensors/gcs_sensor/index.html?highlight=sensor#module-airflow.contrib.sensors.gcs_sensor), which "checks for the existence of a file in Google Cloud Storage." The reason you'd incorporate a sensor is that you're decoupling the operation "determine if a file exists" from the operation "get the file (and do something with it)".

By default, sensors have two methods ([source](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/_modules/airflow/operators/sensors.html)):

- **poke**: the code to run at `poke_interval` times, which tests to see if the condition is true
- **execute**: use the `poke` method to test for a condition on a schedule defined by the `poke_interval`; fails out when the `timeout` argument is reached

In a common file-detection sensor, the operator receives instructions to check a source for a file on a schedule (e.g. check every 5 minutes for up to 3 hours to see if the file exists). If the sensor succeeds in meeting its test condition, it succeeds and allows the DAG to continue downstream to the next operator(s). If it fails to find the file, it times out and the sensor operator is marked failed.

With just a sensor operator, you've already succeeded in separating the error cases - the DAG fails at the `GoogleCloudStorageObjectSensor` instead of the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` when the file doesn't exist, and fails at the `GoogleCloudStorageToBigQueryOperator` when something is wrong with the transfer logic. Importantly for your use case, Airflow supports a `soft_fail` argument, which "mark[s] the task as SKIPPED on failure"

For this next part, I'll caveat this next part by explicitly stating that I'm not intimately familiar with the `GoogleCloudStorage` operators. If the operator doesn't allow wildcarding in the sensor,  you may need to rewire the sensor's `poke` method to allow for more complex, pattern based file detection. This is where Airflow's plug-in architecture can really shine, allowing you to modify and extend existing operators to meet your exact needs.

The example I'll give you here is that the `SFTPSensor` only supports poking for a specific file out of the box. I needed wildcard based poking, so I wrote a plugin that modifies the `SFTPSensor` to support regular expressions in file identification. In my case, it was just modifying the `poke` to switch from polling for the existence of a single file to polling a list of files and then passing it through a regular expression to filter the list.

At a cursory glance, it looks like the way that the `GoogleCloudStorageSensor` pokes for an object is with the [`hook.exists`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/code.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.GoogleCloudStorageHook.exists) method. I can't speak to whether a wildcard would work there, but if it doesn't, it looks like there's a [`hook.list`](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/1.9.0/code.html#airflow.contrib.hooks.GoogleCloudStorageHook.list) method which would allow you to implement a similar workflow to what I did for the `SFTPRegexSensor`.

I've included some of the source code for the SFTPRegexSensor Plugin's `poke` method, modified for how I *think* it'd work with GCS in case it's helpful:

```
def poke(self, context): 
    # create a hook (removed some of the SSH/SFTP intricacies for simplicity)
    # get list of file(s) matching regex 
    files = hook.list(self.bucket, self.prefix) # you need to define operator paramters for the choices that are dynamic in the operator's poke (e.g. which bucket, what the file prefix is); swapped in the GCS args 
    regex = re.compile(self.remote_filename) 
    files = list(filter(regex.search, files)) 

    if not files: 
        return False 
    return True
```